# Check if bucket has water left

Tags: avr, resistors

I want to build starter and simple auto self-watering system.
I need the pump to take the water from a bucket, which means I need to check the water level on it and alert if too low.

I want to do it as simple as I can. Do you think something like this will work? [YouTube Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kL4vvD6oOs)

In the video you can see the following diagram:
[image: Diagram]
While the water will be on the 2 cables end.

I will implement it on Attiny85.

Thanks to @ignacio-vazquez-abrams I found this product:
[image: water level].
I will try it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think posting a youtube video is going to get much of a response - try explaining the idea?

Comment: Float switches are usually a better idea than immersion sensing, if you don't need to precisely know the amount of water.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Updated the question. you can switch the comment to answer so I can mark it. I did not knew switches like this exists :) This is exactly what i need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immersion sensors are useful if you need precise sensing of the amount of water in the container, but suffer from corrosion issues due to both electrolytic removal of the probe material as well as oxidization of same.

If only a rough sense of how much water is required then a [float switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float_switch) is a better solution since the electronics can be made water-tight, thereby reducing corrosion to negligible levels.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. Just a quick question, does the example i gave is immersion sensor? Does it efficient? Did it really work? I mean , 2 cables in the water?

Comment: It works provided that the water is not distilled or deionized. It depends on ions in the water to transport electrons from one probe to the other.